# If(tosString.call(input)!=="[object Array]" can't understand this

Tags: javascript

I can't understand the if statement  and what it is saying and why there is no else statement

```
function max(input) {
         if (toString.call(input) !== "[object Array]")  
           return false;
      return Math.max.apply(null, input);
        }

    console.log(max([12,34,56,1]));
    console.log(max([-12,-34,0,-56,-1]))

;
```

Comment: Modern code would use `if (!Array.isArray(input)) return false;`

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the if statement checks if the input is array.

You don't need an else statement in a function where there is a return statement inside the true branch of the if statement.

In that case anything after the if statement will only run when the condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

That is checking wither the `input` parameter is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

The default toString() implementation of Array returns the string `[object Array]`, so we are checking that to make sure the value is of type Array. You can directly call `toString()` on `input` but then you need to make sure that `input` has a value other than `null` or `undefined`, so instead we are calling the `window` object's toString() method but the context as the `input` value